# I can't scroll Arduino IDE's example & scketch lists down

Tags: arduino-ide

I have Arduino IDE 1.0.5 in win7 x64. I have so many library units. A pity that I can't scroll down to my other options. Is it Arduino.exe's problem or something else? How can I add triangle to scroll down and scroll up to see whole Sketchbook and Examples list? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 1.5.+. It has scroll arrows to allow larger lists of menus, bigger than the screen.

I find that most, if not all, sketches work equally well, if not better.

Up to 1.5.6r2 uses the same version of compiler as 1.0.+'s. 1.5.7 and newer uses a new compiler, that is more sctrict. All stock libraries work. And well written 3rd parties work. I personally use 1.5 and test backwards to 1.0.

There is a fork of 1.0 called ERW that has the scrolling. But 8t is becoming obsolete.

Comment: I downloaded this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=118440.435 And your answer is also good to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the examples in Explorer. Just go to `My Documents`\ `Arduino`\ `libraries`\ `<library-name>`\ `examples`.

This one made me chuckle. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Yes I know this way but I need two triangle to down the list. Thank you for your answer but I didn't want this.